# How do I read two slots from an array and combine them using a recursive function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to implement a calculator using VBA. I am facing trouble with calculating the result using recursion.

I've tried implementing the function. I always end up getting the result to be zero.

Idea:

For example, 2+3+4+5 is to be calculated

The function will recursively read and combine two elements with every step. For instance, at step 2, from the first position, the first two slots of the array give you "2" and "+" so you know that you need to add 2 to the rest of the array starting from position 3. Finally, the result of the array would be 5 (from step 5) + 4 (from step 4) + 3 (from step 3) + 2 (from step 2) = 14.

Please find the code below. I have tried implementing it but I am getting type mismatch error. "Display" is a string to remember the current display of the calculator.

```
Dim Memory(1 To 100) As String

' The current position used by the calculator inside the memory array
Dim CurrentPos As Integer

' This function is a recursive function for calculating the result of the expression
' stored in the Memory array, starting at the position Pos.
'
' Note that the return value is a Long number. When you calculate the result you need
' to convert the numbers (as text) in the memory to long numbers using CLng().
Function CalcTotal(ByVal Pos As Integer) As Long
    '
    ' Task 4: Calculating the Result Using Recursion
    '

    ' Case 1: if Pos is bigger than what you have in the Memory array

        ' Nothing is available

    ' Case 2: if Pos is exactly at the end of the Memory array

        ' Return the number in the position

    ' Case 3: Memory(Pos) is a number and Memory(Pos + 1) is an operator

        ' Return the number in the current position together with the rest of the Memory array
    If Pos > CurrentPos Then ' Case 1: Nothing left to read
        Display = "0"
        'return 0 as the result because there is nothing to do...
    ElseIf Pos = CurrentPos Then ' Case 2: There is only a number left
        Display = CLng(Memory(Pos))
        'return the number in the current position...
    Else ' Case 3: Read the next two slots of the array and combine with the rest of the array
        Display = CLng(Memory(Pos)) + CLng(Memory(Pos + 1))
        CalcTotal (Pos + 2)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I can do it without recursion , do you want it ?

Please post de full code

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a homework problem and I need to do it with recursion. Thank you but sorry :/

Comment: Please can you show a worked example e.g. sample input to your function and the expected result.

Comment: Input : 2+3+4+5
1) From the first position, the first two slots of the array give you "2" and "+" so you know that you need to add 2 to the rest of the array starting from position 3, i.e. Array from slot 3
2) Then, given this array Array from slot 3, you read the first two slots and you know that you need to add 3 to the rest of the array starting from position 5, i.e. Array from slot 5

Comment: 3) Again, you repeat the process by reading the first two slots, i.e. "4" and "+" and then move on to handle the array starting from position 7, i.e. Array from slot 7
4) This array, Array from slot 7, contains only a "5" and therefore you can safely know that the value for this part of the array is 5.

Comment: Is the input a string (e.g. `"2+3+4+5"`) or an array (e.g. `[2,+,3,+,4,+5]`)?

Comment: The latter one, @AlexP.

Comment: That is, `[2,+,3,+,4,+,5]`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started:

```
Public MyInputs As Variant

Sub Test()
    MyInputs = Array("2", "+", "3", "+", "4", "+", "5")
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(CalcTotal(UBound(MyInputs)))  '~~> prints 14
End Sub

Function CalcTotal(n As Integer) As String
    If n = 0 Then
        CalcTotal = MyInputs(n)
    Else
        CalcTotal = MyInputs(n) & (CalcTotal(n - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Notes:

- `CalcTotal` will return a string e.g. `5+4+3+2`
- `Application.Evaluate` parses that string as a computation and prints `14`

Comment: Thank you @Alex. However, I am still getting a type mismatch error in the operator part. Sorry to bother you, as I am new to programming.

Comment: Error in this line `CalcTotal = CLng(Memory(Pos + 1)) & (CalcTotal(Pos - 1))` CLng(Memory(Pos+1)) is the operator part and I am converting it into Long. I do not understand why is still there an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is , You are returning a String "0" , for a function who returns LONG , the correction is replace the "0" (string) to a 0 (long).

```
' This function is a recursive function for calculating the result of the expression
' stored in the Memory array, starting at the position Pos.
'
' Note that the return value is a Long number. When you calculate the result you need
' to convert the numbers (as text) in the memory to long numbers using CLng().
Function CalcTotal(ByVal Pos As Integer) As Long
    '
    ' Task 4: Calculating the Result Using Recursion
    '

    ' Case 1: if Pos is bigger than what you have in the Memory array

        ' Nothing is available

    ' Case 2: if Pos is exactly at the end of the Memory array

        ' Return the number in the position

    ' Case 3: Memory(Pos) is a number and Memory(Pos + 1) is an operator

        ' Return the number in the current position together with the rest of the Memory array
    If Pos > CurrentPos Then ' Case 1: Nothing left to read
        ' Display = "0" WRONG THATS A STRING
          Display = 0
        'return 0 as the result because there is nothing to do...
    ElseIf Pos = CurrentPos Then ' Case 2: There is only a number left
        Display = CLng(Memory(Pos))
        'return the number in the current position...
    Else ' Case 3: Read the next two slots of the array and combine with the rest of the array
        Display = CLng(Memory(Pos)) + CLng(Memory(Pos + 1))
        CalcTotal (Pos + 2)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I am getting an error in `Display = CLng(Memory(Pos)) + CLng(Memory(Pos + 1))`

Comment: I understand, but I have absolutely no idea how to solve the error. I am open to new suggestions. The above code is what I have **tried** personally to arrive at the solution.